# How can I change the background color of div if the condition is met?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Here is the code for notification code:

```
<?php if(isset($notification) && $notification->result() >0 ){?>
    <div class="panel-heading pull-right col-md-6"
    style="height:140px; margin-top:-140px; background-color:white; overflow-y: scroll;">
        <h5><strong>Student with 3 Consecutive Absences</strong></h5>
            <table class="table">
                <thead>
                    <th>Course Code-Section</th>
                    <th>Student Name</th>
                    <th>View</th>
                </thead>
            <tbody>
                <?php foreach($notification->result() as $notif)
                {
                    if($notif->Total >=3)
                    {
                    ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td><?php echo $notif->Course_Code_Section?</td>
                            <td><?php echo $notif->Student?></td>
                            <td>
                                <form action="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/attendance/check" method="post" target="_blank">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="CID" value="<?php echo $notif->CID;?>">
                                    <button class="btn btn-xs btn-success"><i class="icon-eye-open"></i> View</button>
                                <?php echo form_close();?>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        </div>
                        <?php }?>
                    <?php }?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
    </div>
<?php }?>
```

Here is the notification view, the default background color is white. Therefore, I want it to make the background color red when the condition met.

[image: Notification View]

Comment: conditionally add a class inside the tag like `class="red"` then just declare `.red{background-color;}` in your css.  Did you try anything before writing this question?  Did you research at all?  This is such a low value question, please consider deleting it to reduce question bloat on SO.

Comment: what is your condition - @ Ronnel Gonzales

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?php
$style = '';
if(isset($notification) && $notification->result() > 0 )
{
    $style = 'style="color:red"';
    // Put your css style property here
}
?>
```

Html:

```
<div <?php echo $style ?>>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your condition is true in PHP you can just this line in your  tag:

```
<tr bgcolor="#FF0000">
```

I don't know if my html code will appear or not. Please refer this site:

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_tr_bgcolor.asp

Comment: When you need to place code in answer or question indent by 4 spaces

Answer (score 0):

You can do as -

```
<?php
if(your condition)
{
 ?>   
   <style>
#your_div
{
 background:red !important;
}
</style>
<?php
}
else
{
?>   
   <style>
#your_div
{
 background:white !important;
}
</style>
<?php
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code ,i hope this is your condition

```
 <?php 
$bcolor ='background-color:white';
if(isset($notification) && $notification->result() >0 ){
$bcolor ='background-color:white';
 }?>
    <div class="panel-heading pull-right col-md-6"
    style="height:140px; margin-top:-140px; <?php echo $bcolor ;?> overflow-y: scroll;">
        <h5><strong>Student with 3 Consecutive Absences</strong></h5>
            <table class="table">
                <thead>
                    <th>Course Code-Section</th>
                    <th>Student Name</th>
                    <th>View</th>
                </thead>
            <tbody>
                <?php foreach($notification->result() as $notif)
                {
                    if($notif->Total >=3)
                    {
                    ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td><?php echo $notif->Course_Code_Section?</td>
                            <td><?php echo $notif->Student?></td>
                            <td>
                                <form action="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/attendance/check" method="post" target="_blank">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="CID" value="<?php echo $notif->CID;?>">
                                    <button class="btn btn-xs btn-success"><i class="icon-eye-open"></i> View</button>
                                <?php echo form_close();?>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        </div>
                        <?php }?>
                    <?php }?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
<?php 
    $bg_red = '';
    if (condition) {
       $bg_red = '<style="background-color: red;">';
    }
?>

<tr <php? echo $bg_red; ?>>
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
</tr>
```